# Navigation Drawer and sliding Tabs

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I want to use navigation drawer and tabs together.I have googled it but i didn't get correct answer,even I am confused whether to use or not when i use navigation drawer I use the FrameLayout and for tab also I use FrameLayout how do i differentiate them how can I use.Can anyone explain me.Previously action bar were there but, now they are deprecated. I am using toolbar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/DrawerWithTabsAndViewPager

Comment: can i import this in android studio I am new to android studio

Comment: yes you can .see the link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Comment: I have done this, and it is easy if you combine this  library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu    and this tutorial    http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use navigation drawer and tabs together.

Why? Navigation Drawer gives user clickable options and when an item is selected, developer has to change the fragment in the Activity's FrameLayout.

Tab view is also an alternative, i.e. you can have all drawer options in form of 'swipe-able' tabbed fragments, using viewPager.

Now you should decide, to go with drawer or viewPager

Alternatively, if you do want to use both in your app you can go for a viewpager inside slidingDrawer. Now ViewPager will have tabbed swipe view and slidingDrawer options can open new Activities.

Let me know of your decision and then I can update here with appropriate code snippet/links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Exactly what you said it correct but if i use activities for sliding menu it may take more about of memory(ram) compare to view pager when an item is selected.I prefer second option where i can go sliding menu onclick for activities and viewpager for tabs but when i try this  i can see only one either sliding menu or tabs